# What is alternative of SET DEFINE OFF in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I am executing insert queries in T-SQL (SQL Server).

But in my insert queries there is a `&` and some other special characters are there in values.

My query is like

```
INSERT INTO table (A, B, C) 
VALUES ('xyz', 'wer&ert', 'mnb');
```

I have used `SET DEFINE OFF` in Oracle for this issue.

But I don't know the alternative of `SET DEFINE OFF`.

Can anybody help with this?

Comment: You don't have to do anything in `SQL SERVER`. `&` will be considered as string just like other characters

Comment: What is your desired result? If you want to end up with the literal values `xyz`, `wer&ert` and `mnb` in your table, what you already have will do this.

Comment: @3N1GM4 yes I want to store the values as  'xyz' , 'wer&ert' and 'mnb'

Comment: @VivekSharma Then as [Prdp](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3349551/prdp) and I have suggested, the `INSERT` statement you already have should do this - what result do you get, or what problem are you having?

Answer (score 0):

In strings special characters are characters and it isn't necessary escape them. Variable in mssql (prefixed with @) isn't quoted (formal exception can be $ in dynamic qries (it's sign of pseudovariable)).

```
select 'string' -- string
select '@string' -- string
select @variable -- variable
select @@globalvariable -- variable
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server Management Studio, you can use the command "SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF" to achieve the same functionality as "SET DEFINE OFF" in Oracle SQL*Plus.

This command disables the interpretation of double quotation marks as delimiters for identifiers and string literals. It also disables the interpretation of the single quotation mark as a prefix character for escape sequences.

To disable the interpretation of double quotation marks as delimiters in SQL Server Management Studio, you can use the following command:
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF;